# How to truncate all file content assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, truncate, tasm

I'm using Assembly x86 with TASM.
I'm trying to truncate all file content, but I couldn't find any interrupt for that.
Is it my only option to delete and recreate it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With MS-DOS?  What do you mean by "clear" or "clean"?  Do you mean you want to truncate the file?

Comment: Yes, excuse me. I meant to truncate all data in it.

Comment: You can use `int 21h / ah = 3ch` to open and truncate the file, and then immediately close it again with `ah = 3eh`.

Comment: When you have opened a file for writing and you're seeked to the beginning (interrupt 21h service 4200h, `cx:dx` = 0, `bx` = handle) then you can call interrupt 21h service 40h with `bx` = handle and `cx` = 0 to truncate the file.